# SignalR how to call 2 different method in 1 Hub?

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

So I have 2 methods in 1 hub:

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public void SendMessage(string name, string message)
    {
        Clients.All.AddMessage(name, message);
    }

    public void SendAnnounce(string name)
    {
        Clients.Others.AddMessage(name);
    }
}
```

How do you properly use 2 methods together in 1 hub in client side javascript?

I have this in javascript,

for SendMessage(string name, string message) hub method:

```
            var message = $("#txtMessage").val();
            var userid = $("#lblUsername").html();
            chat.client.addMessage = function (frm, msg) {
                $messages.append("[" + frm + "] " + msg);
            }
```

invoke:

```
            chat.server.sendMessage(userid, input);
```

for SendAnnounce(string name) hub method:

```
            chat.client.addMessage = function (frm) {
                $announcement.append("<div>test</div>");
            }
```

invoke:

```
            var userid = $("#txtUsername").val();
            chat.server.announcement(userid);
```

But it doesn't work(server just uses the last method in my case announcement one).
It works only if I make 2 hubs and put each method in different hubs, then create different variables for each hub like this:

```
                //Create Hub on Air
            var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
            var chat2 = $.connection.announcementHub;
```

then work with 1 method with "chat" variable and with second method with "chat2" variable.. Then it works. Like this:

```
            chat.client.addMessage = function (frm, msg) {
                $messages.append("[" + frm + "] " + msg);
            }
            chat2.client.addMessage = function (frm) {
                $announcement.append("<div> test</div>");
                });
            }
```

What do I not understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript you can't really have method overloads. What you are doing is first declaring `addMessage` to be a function with two parameters and then overwrite that with a function with one parameter. So the last one is being used

Either use methods that are named differently, e.g. `addMessage` and `addAnnouncement` or use a single method and check if second parameter is defined. If it is not then it is an announcement.

Answer (score 0):

I actually got This working! calling two methods in one isntance. What i dont understand is why your creating two live connections? you will only ever need one.